# how to assign variable value after window onload

Tags: javascript

How to show the textboxes.....see. The max value I will assign after onload so following code did not work........

max value is equal to the user selected files count.
I cant assign before onload the page..

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="store(this); return false">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="prev" onclick="goto(this.form, -1)" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" onclick="goto(this.form, +1)" value="Next" />
    </p>
    <divs>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
    </divs>
    <div id="filename"></div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store in database" />
    </p>
</form>




 <!-------------user selected file's name in array------------------>
 var filelist=new Array();
          function insert(filess) 
             {
                filelist[filelist.length]=filess; 
                var sahan=(filelist.valueOf());
               }


max=filelist.length;

window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = form.getElementsByTagName('divs')[0];
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        container.innerHTML += '<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + max + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    goto(form, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are too many issues to mention.

1. you need to get the maximum before you use it, so call insert and from there issue the call to build the list
2. you need to either pass the maximum around OR make it global in scope
3. you are using two different ajax methods
4. you are not using jQuery everywhere and so on.

Here is a working demo when maximum is set before onload.

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rnJWX/

```
var maximum=0, current = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    maximum=10;
    var container = $("#sankar");
    container.hide();
    container.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
      container.append('<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + maximum + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>');
    }    
    goto(form, 0);
    container.show();
})


function goto(form, pos) {
    current += pos;
    $('#my_div').html("Hiding all "+maximum+" sets and showing set #"+current+"..."); // sankar[curent];
    form.prev.disabled = current <= 0;
    form.next.disabled = current >= maximum - 1;
// you can do jQuery here too
    var fields = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) fields[i].style.display = 'none';
    fields[current].style.display = 'block';
    form['name' + current].focus();
}
```

Comment: hi....but initially alltextboxes is showing.....when i click the next or prev button it work properly.............how to solve......

Comment: u see......http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/gAVZ8/    ....initially all textboxes is showing............

Comment: realy ...sir....in your script initialy all textboxes(Files of 1/10,Files of 2/10,Files of 3/10.......upto Files of 10/10) is showing. after if i click the next or prev button it is work properly.........please correct for me..........

Comment: u see..sir.........http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/gAVZ8/11/ but did not work properly......

Comment: please tell me sir........why initialy is showing all textboxes........what is the reason......

Comment: hi...Mr.mplungjan....help me.....i have tried......but it not work properly sir.....only one question sir...why it is showing all textbox initialy..........

Comment: Because they are not hidden until you do goto. If you hide your container and show it in goto, then the user will not see them all

Comment: Do a container.hide(); container.empty(); for ... container.append(...); goto(0); container.show();

Comment: See my update. Hide the container, empty the container, fill the container, select the first item then show the container.

Comment: this is not working sir.....function starts(values)
{
 maximum=values;
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = $("#sankar");
    container.hide();
    container.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
      container.append('<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + maximum + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>');
    }    
    goto(form, 0);
    container.show();
}

Comment: if i select 3 file so initialy is showing 6 textbox(Files of 1/3,Files of 2/3,Files of 3/3)after if i click the next or prev button it is showing correctly per each click 2 textbox....please give me idea to solve the bug........

Comment: good......it is possible if i set the maximum value before onload the page..........but i have an array value and array length.....u see .........so i want set the array length to maximum value..........is it possible.......i think IF it is possible....i can clear.......so how set the array length(sankar.length)=maximum; u see.....ALSO I DON'T KNOWN HOW TO CALL THE starts(values) BECAUSE IF I SELECTE 4 FILE THE FUNCTION CALL 4 TIME SO INITIALLY IS SHOWING ALL TEXT BOX. HOW TO CALL THE starts(values) ONLY ONE TIME.....U SEE http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/YWxLQ/11/

Comment: I really have no idea where you call your insert. You need to create a test site with the pages you need. I STILL have not understood when the insert is called. I will no longer help you unless you make a website with the pages you have. It can be a test server. If you do not want to show a url here, email me from my website plungjan.name

Comment: simply i explain u sir.    name(filess) into the filess user selected files are there...ok....so how get the file names and count......if i get count and names ...i can clear...otherwise i can't clear....so please explai me........HOW GET THE FILES NAME AND COUNT.......

Comment: please give me idea......how get file'name and total file(count) because count =maximum; i will set.......see this is correct or not...... var sankar=new Array();
function name(filess) 
{
 sankar = filess;
 var sahan =(sankar.valueOf());
 alert(sankar.length);
 alert(sahan);
}

Comment: sorry I have no idea without seeing the flow of actions the user needs to take. Please do as I asked and make a (set of) page(s) to show the flow the user needs to take to upload.

Comment: u see my js...this is upload.js sir........if u see that u known that how i got the filename.................and tell me how get the file names and count.from that..........I HAVE MENTION <!--MPLUNGJAN-->U SEE http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/YWxLQ/12/

Comment: I am sorry you are frustrated but so am I. You keep throwing completely unconnected javascript at me. What you just posted does not tell me anything at all. I will now stop this communication until you give me a url of a site where you have put the html that shows the user something and then we can take it from there.

Comment: ok..thank u sir.....now i am trying...if any doubt i will send message you...............

Comment: hi...sir ..i have tried but i could not find it sir......i think any problem in folowing code:  var fields = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) 
 
 {fields[i].style.display ='none';
 }
    fields[current].style.display = 'block';
 alert(current);
    form['name' + current].focus();

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you've given your "container" element an ID, you should use `document.getElementById('divs')` instead of `form.getElementsByTagName('divs')[0]`.
In your current code, `container` would be `undefined`.

Comment: hi,  i have used.. var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = form.getElementById('divs'); but did not work.....

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` works and so does `document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`

Comment: @MVS800824 You should use `document.getElementById('divs')`, not `form.getElementById('divs')`

Comment: this is correct or not........ var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = document.getElementById('divs');

Comment: see my dear friend.....i have used......this.....window.onload = function() {
 
var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = document.getElementById('divs');
 container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    container.innerHTML += '<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + 5 + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    goto(form, 0);
 
 }   but did not work........

Comment: Well then, what part of it fails? As far as i can tell, the answer from @mplungjan indicates, that it should work - even when using your original code.

Comment: according to mplungjan......only work...if form and js in one page(that means single page) otherwise did not work......

Comment: Okay - just to make sure - your code IS called, right? (Sorry if that's a stupid question)

Comment: hi.....ok how do it........if that's wrong...ok... tell me how do it.........this code is used to get the description for each file ...i have done all work.....ecept this....only i want how to show textboxes....please hepl me......very urgent......u have any other idea......that's ok......tell me.....

Comment: Well, I've tried looking at it, and from what I can tell, the window.onload method is not ever run.. I've tried attaching the event to both window and body, with no luck.. I'm all out of answers, sorry.